# Making an old fashioned (Windows 95-esque) GUI in Java

Tags: java, look-and-feel, appearance

I'm currently working on a project and I'd like it to look as though it were from the windows 95 era. I spent a lot of time searching for a pluggable Look and Feel that matched the Windows 95 aesthetic, but everything I could find looked too rounded, streamlined and modern. Can anyone suggest a retro, kind of clunky looking look and feel that I can use? If not, is there any other way that I could get this aesthetic in Java?

Comment: just take a screen shot and show it on bootup. it doesnt need interaction, because an authentic win95 system will crash immediately lol

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html) for `UIManager.setLookAndFeel()`.

I'm thinking either `UIManager.setLookAndFeel(javax.swing.plaf.metal)` or `UIManager.setLookAndFeel(javax.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsClassic)` should give you the look you want.

Comment: Wouldn't `WindowsClassic` be more appropriate?  `Metal` was the "default" cross-platform look and feel before Nimbus

Comment: Ya, sorry. I had used `metal` before and not `WindowsClassic`, so it was my goto right away. Edit made.

Answer (score -1):

check JGoodies site http://www.jgoodies.com/freeware/libraries/looks/ 
it says 
"Precise Windows Emulation

Our Windows look&feel focuses on a precise emulation on Windows 95, 98, NT, ME, 2000, XP, Vista, 7, and now Windows 8 in the following areas: menus, icons, colors, borders, fonts, font sizes, insets, and widget dimensions. It honors the screen resolution (96dpi vs. 120 dpi) to adjust sizes, insets, and widget dimensions."

Comment: Nope. The JGoodies Looks 2.5.3 (latest available version) Windows L&F only works if the application is run on a Windows operating system ☹

Comment: OP didn't mention which OS he needs it to run.